# error "No more data is available." when trying to connect and disconnect from a Wi-FI using python

Tags: python, windows, python-requests

i want to write a code that can connect, disconnect and check if internet is available using the following python code

```python
import subprocess
import requests
import time

def disconnect_wifi():
    """Disconnects the current Wi-Fi connection on Windows."""
    try:
        # Disable the Wi-Fi adapter.
        subprocess.run(["netsh", "interface", "set", "interface", "name='Wi-Fi'", "admin=disable"], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error disconnecting Wi-Fi: {str(e)}")

def connect_to_wifi(ssid, password):
    """Connects to the specified Wi-Fi network on Windows."""
    try:
        # Enable the Wi-Fi adapter.
        subprocess.run(["netsh", "interface", "set", "interface", "name='Wi-Fi'", "admin=enable"], check=True)

        # Connect to the Wi-Fi network using the provided SSID and password.
        subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "connect", "ssid", ssid, "name", ssid, "keyMaterial", password], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to Wi-Fi: {str(e)}")

def check_internet_access():
    """Checks if internet access is available."""
    try:
        # Try to connect to a website.
        requests.get("https://google.com")
        return True
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False

def main():
    ssid = "Wifi name"  # Replace with your SSID
    password = "Wifi passord"  # Replace with your password

    # Disconnect the current Wi-Fi connection.
    disconnect_wifi()
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the adapter to disable.

    # Connect to the specified Wi-Fi network.
    connect_to_wifi(ssid, password)
    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the adapter to connect.

    # Check if internet access is available.
    if check_internet_access():
        print("Internet access is available.")
    else:
        print("Internet access is not available.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but every time i run the code i get

```
###########
No more data is available.

Error disconnecting Wi-Fi: Command '['netsh', 'interface', 'set', 'interface', "name='Wi-Fi'", 'admin=disable']' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
       
No more data is available.


Error connecting to Wi-Fi: Command '['netsh', 'interface', 'set', 'interface', "name='Wi-Fi'", 'admin=enable']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Internet access is available.
```

it does not disconnect from a Wi-Fi
does not connect to a Wi-Fi
but it manages to accurately tell if internet is available or not

i tried

to Restart my computer.
Check your Wi-Fi adapter driver. made sure that it is up to date.
Reset my network settings.

Comment: Perhaps if you use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html "link to docs -->") and capture the output, etc., instead of `os.system`, you might get some additional information.

Comment: error with subprocess.run 
No more data is available.


Error disconnecting Wi-Fi: Command '['netsh', 'interface', 'set', 'interface', "name='Wi-Fi'", 'admin=disable']' returned non-zero exit status 1.        
No more data is available.


Error connecting to Wi-Fi: Command '['netsh', 'interface', 'set', 'interface', "name='Wi-Fi'", 'admin=enable']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: When you have new info related to your question, you should edit your question and add the info there.  Here you should show the new code and any/all output and/or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution the cmd commands i passed were outdated here is an updated code

```
import subprocess
import requests
import time

def disconnect_wifi():
    """Disconnects the current Wi-Fi connection on Windows."""
    try:
        # Disable the Wi-Fi adapter.
        subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "disconnect"], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error disconnecting Wi-Fi: {str(e)}")

def connect_to_wifi():
    """Connects to the specified Wi-Fi network on Windows."""
    try:
        
        subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "connect", "ssid=HOME","name=HOME"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to Wi-Fi: {str(e)}")

def check_internet_access():
    """Checks if internet access is available."""
    try:
        # Try to connect to a website.
        requests.get("https://google.com")
        return True
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False

def main():
    # Disconnect the current Wi-Fi connection.
    disconnect_wifi()
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the adapter to disable.

    # Connect to the specified Wi-Fi network.
    connect_to_wifi()
    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the adapter to connect.

    # Check if internet access is available.
    if check_internet_access():
        print("Internet access is available.")
    else:
        print("Internet access is not available.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this code now manages to disconnect and connect to a saved wifi network named HOME and check if internet access is available